# Weather API modification in google script

Tags: highcharts

I am running a script in google sheets that uses an API from Wunderground to gather my local weather. I am having issue now when I try to use highcharts as it doesn't like the % sign that comes from the API json. My code is below and I'm trying to figure out how to modify it

```
<Code>
/**
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain data and logs the
 * values for each row.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
var cDay = 0, cTemp = 1, cRH = 2, cWinddegree = 3;
var cWindspeed = 4, cWindgust = 5;
var nCols = 7;



function getTemp() {
  var url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/***************/conditions/q/44.1,-77.3.json';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var contentText = response.getContentText();
  var conditions = JSON.parse(contentText);
  var todaysConditions = conditions; 

  var temp = todaysConditions.current_observation.temp_f;
  var rh = todaysConditions.current_observation.relative_humidity;
  var winddir = todaysConditions.current_observation.wind_dir;
  var winddegree = todaysConditions.current_observation.wind_degrees;
  var windspeed = todaysConditions.current_observation.wind_mph;
  var windgust = todaysConditions.current_observation.wind_gust_mph;
  sheet.insertRowAfter(1);

  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,1, nCols);
  var row = range.getValues()[0];
  row[cDay] = new Date ();
  row[cTemp] = temp; 
  row[cRH] = rh;
  row[cWinddegree] = winddegree;
  row[cWindspeed] = windspeed;
  row[cWindgust] = windgust;



  range.setValues([row]);

}
</Code>
```

I believe it is this line I need to modify: 
row[cRH] = rh;

Comment: Please explain why you think “it doesn't like the % sign”. Did it show an error message? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29130754/edit) your question to include the message.

Comment: If your values are percentages, then Highcharts won't work with strings. Parse them to numbers using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I added 'var RH = parseFloat(rh).toFixed(2);' to make it work. originally I got 54% , when I added just the parseFloat I would get 5400%. Adding the toFixed(2) got me the 54 I was looking for.

Comment: `toFixed()` method returns string anyway, so it still can make some problems..

Comment: My script is working very well now and I am happy with my Graph. The issue is now with the Google Gauge feature. It makes a very nice gauge except I get a new gauge every time my script runs. I just want to update the existing one...any ideas??

Comment: @BlueCollarIngenuity could you add the code for your gauge and graph?